# How can suppress the warning info when to verify apache?

Tags: gpg, verification

Warning info "This key is not certified with a trusted signature!" when to verify apache :

```
wget https://downloads.apache.org/accumulo/1.10.2/accumulo-1.10.2-bin.tar.gz
wget https://downloads.apache.org/accumulo/1.10.2/accumulo-1.10.2-bin.tar.gz.asc 
wget  https://downloads.apache.org/accumulo/KEYS
gpg --import KEYS    
gpg --verify accumulo-1.10.2-bin.tar.gz.asc accumulo-1.10.2-bin.tar.gz
```

An error info occurs:

```
gpg: Signature made Tue 08 Feb 2022 11:04:00 PM HKT
gpg:                using RSA key 8CC4F8A2B29C2B040F2B835D6F0CDAE700B6899D
gpg: Good signature from "Christopher L Tubbs II (Christopher) <ctubbsii@gmail.com>" [unknown]
gpg:                 aka "Christopher L Tubbs II (Developer) <ctubbsii@apache.org>" [unknown]
gpg:                 aka "Christopher L Tubbs II (Developer) <ctubbsii@fedoraproject.org>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 8CC4 F8A2 B29C 2B04 0F2B  835D 6F0C DAE7 00B6 899D
```

I want to trust it fully:

```
gpg --edit-key   8CC4F8A2B29C2B040F2B835D6F0CDAE700B6899D
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27; Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.


pub  rsa4096/6F0CDAE700B6899D
     created: 2012-10-13  expires: 2024-01-12  usage: SC  
     trust: full          validity: unknown
sub  rsa4096/2FFC0085C23D3DA9
     created: 2012-10-13  expires: 2024-01-12  usage: E   
sub  rsa4096/4417A0C14245D003
     created: 2013-04-28  expires: 2024-01-12  usage: A   
[ unknown] (1). Christopher L Tubbs II (Christopher) <ctubbsii@gmail.com>
[ unknown] (2)  Christopher L Tubbs II (Developer) <ctubbsii@apache.org>
[ unknown] (3)  Christopher L Tubbs II (Developer) <ctubbsii@fedoraproject.org>

gpg> trust
pub  rsa4096/6F0CDAE700B6899D
     created: 2012-10-13  expires: 2024-01-12  usage: SC  
     trust: full          validity: unknown
sub  rsa4096/2FFC0085C23D3DA9
     created: 2012-10-13  expires: 2024-01-12  usage: E   
sub  rsa4096/4417A0C14245D003
     created: 2013-04-28  expires: 2024-01-12  usage: A   
[ unknown] (1). Christopher L Tubbs II (Christopher) <ctubbsii@gmail.com>
[ unknown] (2)  Christopher L Tubbs II (Developer) <ctubbsii@apache.org>
[ unknown] (3)  Christopher L Tubbs II (Developer) <ctubbsii@fedoraproject.org>

Please decide how far you trust this user to correctly verify other users' keys
(by looking at passports, checking fingerprints from different sources, etc.)

  1 = I don't know or won't say
  2 = I do NOT trust
  3 = I trust marginally
  4 = I trust fully
  5 = I trust ultimately
  m = back to the main menu

Your decision? 4

pub  rsa4096/6F0CDAE700B6899D
     created: 2012-10-13  expires: 2024-01-12  usage: SC  
     trust: full          validity: unknown
sub  rsa4096/2FFC0085C23D3DA9
     created: 2012-10-13  expires: 2024-01-12  usage: E   
sub  rsa4096/4417A0C14245D003
     created: 2013-04-28  expires: 2024-01-12  usage: A   
[ unknown] (1). Christopher L Tubbs II (Christopher) <ctubbsii@gmail.com>
[ unknown] (2)  Christopher L Tubbs II (Developer) <ctubbsii@apache.org>
[ unknown] (3)  Christopher L Tubbs II (Developer) <ctubbsii@fedoraproject.org>

gpg> quit
```

Then to verify again:

```
gpg --verify accumulo-1.10.2-bin.tar.gz.asc accumulo-1.10.2-bin.tar.gz  
gpg: Signature made Tue 08 Feb 2022 11:04:00 PM HKT
gpg:                using RSA key 8CC4F8A2B29C2B040F2B835D6F0CDAE700B6899D
gpg: Good signature from "Christopher L Tubbs II (Christopher) <ctubbsii@gmail.com>" [unknown]
gpg:                 aka "Christopher L Tubbs II (Developer) <ctubbsii@apache.org>" [unknown]
gpg:                 aka "Christopher L Tubbs II (Developer) <ctubbsii@fedoraproject.org>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 8CC4 F8A2 B29C 2B04 0F2B  835D 6F0C DAE7 00B6 899D
```

How can suppress the warning info when to verify apache ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either setting trust to ultimate (5), or signing the key, will do the trick (**but** see the caveat below!).

#### Option 1: set trust to ultimate

```
$ gpg --edit-key 8CC4F8A2B29C2B040F2B835D6F0CDAE700B6899D

[...]

gpg> trust

[...]

Please decide how far you trust this user to correctly verify other users' keys
(by looking at passports, checking fingerprints from different sources, etc.)

  1 = I don't know or won't say
  2 = I do NOT trust
  3 = I trust marginally
  4 = I trust fully
  5 = I trust ultimately
  m = back to the main menu

Your decision? 5
Do you really want to set this key to ultimate trust? (y/N) y

[...]

gpg> quit
```

Notice that I entered 5 at the trust prompt. Now when I run the verify command:

```
$ gpg --verify accumulo-1.10.2-bin.tar.gz.asc accumulo-1.10.2-bin.tar.gz
```

There is no longer a warning in the output. On the other hand, I did lie when I set the trust to ultimate.

#### Option 2: sign the key

Since you do not ultimately trust the key, it is more correct to sign the key with your own, ultimately trusted, key. If you want to do some diligence first, see the caveat. To sign the key:

```
$ gpg --sign-key 8CC4F8A2B29C2B040F2B835D6F0CDAE700B6899D

[...]

Really sign all user IDs? (y/N) y

[...]

Really sign? (y/N) y
```

Again there is no warning when I run the verify command, and this time I did not have to lie.

#### Caveat

Do be aware that the warning is there for good reason. If you want to spend some more effort trying to determine whether you do trust the key, before signing it or marking it as ultimately trusted, [this security.stackexchange.com thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/96314/how-to-verify-an-openpgp-keys-ownership) is a good starting point.