# The difference between sign-key and edit-key

Tags: gpg

An issue based on [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/698565/how-can-suppress-the-warning-info-when-to-verify-apache).

If you want to trust a public key, two commands can achieve the target:

```
gpg --edit-key   someone's_public_key
gpg --sign-key   someone's_public_key
```

The obvious point that i can find is you have 6 choice to choose in `--edit-key`:

```
gpg> sign

  1 = I don't know or won't say
  2 = I do NOT trust
  3 = I trust marginally
  4 = I trust fully
  5 = I trust ultimately
  m = back to the main menu
```

Is `gpg --sign-key   someone's_public_key` = `gpg --edit-key   someone's_public_key (option 5)`?
What is the other main points between them?

Comment: Please note that the following may be nonsense because I am not a GPG expert and because I can't test it at the moment. Having said this: I vaguely remember that `--edit-key` provides a sub-command `check` which lets you check the signatures (hopefully including trust levels). Perhaps you can figure it out that way: Use `--sign-key` to sign, then use `--edit-key` with `check` to find out what has happened (notably, which trust level has been set). If this works, I'll add it as an answer. If it's nonsense, I'll just delete that comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `man gpg` says:

```
   --sign-key name
          Signs a public key with your secret key. This is a shortcut version of the subcommand "sign" from --edit.
```

As there is no option `--edit`, but there are `--edit-key` and `--edit-card`, I'd assume they meant `--edit-key`, and it is indeed the same (modulo defaults for choices).

Comment: But there are 6 kinds of status for `--edit-key`,no such status for `--sign-key`.They can't be equal.

Comment: They are not "equal", one is a shortcut.